# (BioPython) How do I stop MemoryError: Out of Memory exception?

Tags: python, memory, out-of-memory, bioinformatics, biopython

I have a program where I take a pair of very large multiple sequence files (>77,000 sequences each averaging about 1000 bp long) and calculate the alignment score between each paired individual element and write that number into an output file (which I will load into an excel file later).

My code works for small multiple sequence files but my large master file will throw the following traceback after analyzing the 16th pair.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Documents\cgigas\BioPython Programs\Score Create Program\scoreCreate", line 109, in <module>
    cycle(f,k,binLen)
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Documents\cgigas\BioPython Programs\Score Create Program\scoreCreate", line 85, in cycle
    a = pairwise2.align.localxx(currentSubject.seq, currentQuery.seq, score_only=True)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\Bio\pairwise2.py", line 301, in __call__
    return _align(**keywds)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\Bio\pairwise2.py", line 322, in _align
    score_only)
MemoryError: Out of memory
```

I have tried many things to work around this (as many of you may see from the code), all to no avail. I have tried splitting the large master file into smaller batches to be fed into score calculating method. I have tried del files after I am done using them, I have tried using my Ubuntu 11.11 on an Oracle Virtual machine (I typically work in 64bit Windows 7). Am I being to ambitious is this computationally feasable in BioPython? Below is my code, I have no experience in memory debugging which is the clear culprit of this problem. Any assistance is greatly appreciated I am becoming very frustrated with this problem.

Best,
Harry

```
    ##Open reference file
##a.)Upload subjectList
##b.)Upload query list (a and b are pairwise data)
## Cycle through each paired FASTA and get alignment score of each(Large file)

from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio import pairwise2
import gc


##BATCH ITERATOR METHOD (not my code)
def batch_iterator(iterator, batch_size) :
    entry = True #Make sure we loop once
    while entry :
        batch = []
        while len(batch) < batch_size :
            try :
                entry = iterator.next()
            except StopIteration :
                entry = None
            if entry is None :
                #End of file
                break
            batch.append(entry)
        if batch :
            yield batch

def split(subject,query):
    ##Query Iterator and Batch Subject Iterator
    query_iterator = SeqIO.parse(query,"fasta")
    record_iter = SeqIO.parse(subject,"fasta")

    ##Writes both large file into many small files
    print "Splitting Subject File..."
    binLen=2
    for j, batch1 in enumerate(batch_iterator(record_iter, binLen)) :
        filename1="groupA_%i.fasta" % (j+1)
        handle1=open(filename1, "w")
        count1 = SeqIO.write(batch1, handle1, "fasta")
        handle1.close()

    print "Done splitting Subject file"
    print "Splitting Query File..."

    for k, batch2 in enumerate(batch_iterator(query_iterator,binLen)):
        filename2="groupB_%i.fasta" % (k+1)
        handle2=open(filename2, "w")
        count2 = SeqIO.write(batch2, handle2, "fasta")
        handle2.close()

    print "Done splitting both FASTA files"
    print " "
    return [k ,binLen]


##This file will hold the alignment scores in a tab deliminated text
f = open("C:\\Users\\Harry\\Documents\\cgigas\\alignScore.txt", 'w')

def cycle(f,k,binLen):
    i=1
    m=1
    while  i<=k+1:
        ##Open the first small file
        subjectFile = open("C:\\Users\\Harry\\Documents\\cgigas\\BioPython Programs\\groupA_" + str(i)+".fasta", "rU")
        queryFile =open("C:\\Users\\Harry\\Documents\\cgigas\\BioPython Programs\\groupB_" + str(i)+".fasta", "rU")
        i=i+1
        j=0


        ##Make small file iterators
        smallQuery=SeqIO.parse(queryFile,"fasta")
        smallSubject=SeqIO.parse(subjectFile,"fasta")

        ##Cycles through both sets of FASTA files
        while j<binLen:
                j=j+1
                currentQuery=smallQuery.next()
                currentSubject=smallSubject.next()
                ##Verify every pair is correct
                print " "
                print "Pair: " +  str(m)
                print "Subject: "+ currentSubject.id
                print "Query: " + currentQuery.id
                gc.collect()
                a = pairwise2.align.localxx(currentSubject.seq, currentQuery.seq, score_only=True)
                gc.collect()
                currentQuery=None
                currentSubject=None
                score=str(a)
                a=None
                print "Score: " + score
                f.write("1"+ "\n")
                m=m+1

        smallQuery.close()
        smallSubject.close()
        subjectFile.close()
        queryFile.close()
        gc.collect()
        print "New file"
##MAIN PROGRAM
##Here is our paired list of FASTA files

##subject = open("C:\\Users\\Harry\\Documents\\cgigas\\subjectFASTA.fasta", "rU")
##query =open("C:\\Users\\Harry\\Documents\\cgigas\\queryFASTA.fasta", "rU")
##[k,binLen]=split(subject,query)
k=272
binLen=2
cycle(f,k,binLen)
```

P.S. Be kind I am aware there is probably some goofy things in the code that I put in there trying to get around this problem.

Comment: P.S.P.S I am not married to the idea of using biopython I just need to get my list of scores from this pair of FASTA files

Comment: Pairwise sequence alignment requires making a matrix that is N*M size, where N and M are the lengths of your two sequences. A 1000x1000 matrix of integers is 4 MB, which should be no problem, but your computer is likely choking on a pair of sequences that are substantially larger than 1KBase. Try printing out the sequence length for each pair to see if that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

See also this very similar question on BioStars, http://www.biostars.org/post/show/45893/trying-to-get-around-memoryerror-out-of-memory-exception-in-biopython-program/

There I suggested trying existing tools for this kind of thing, e.g. EMBOSS needleall http://emboss.open-bio.org/wiki/Appdoc:Needleall (you can parse the EMBOSS alignment output with Biopython)

Answer (score 0):

The `pairwise2` module was updated in the recent version of Biopython (1.68) to become faster and less memory consuming.