# Biopython Global Alignment : Out of Memory

Tags: python, biopython

Im trying the `global alignment` method from the `Biopython` module. Using it on short sequences is easy and gives an alignment matrix straightaway. However I really need to run it on larger sequences I have (an average lenght of `2000 nucleatides (or) characters`). However I keep running into the `Out of Memory` error. I looked on SO and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840467/biopython-how-do-i-stop-memoryerror-out-of-memory-exception) previous question. The answers provided are not helpfull as they link to the [this](http://emboss.open-bio.org/wiki/Appdoc:Needleall) same website which cant be accessed now.Apart from this I have tried these steps:

1. I tried using a `64-bit` python since my personal computer has `4gb` RAM.
2. `ssh`ed to a small school server with `16gb` RAM and tried running on that. Its still running after close to 4 hours.

Since its is a small script im unsure how to modify it. ANy help will be greatly appreciated.

My script:

```
import os
from Bio import pairwise2
from Bio.pairwise2 import format_alignment

file_list = []

file_list = [each for each in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if each.endswith(".dna")]

align_file = open("seq_align.aln","w")

seq_list = []

for each_file in file_list:
    f_o = open(each_file,"r")
    seq_list.append(f_o.read())

for a in pairwise2.align.globalmx(seq_list[0],seq_list[1]):
    align_file.write(format_alignment(*a))

align_file.close()
```

Comment: How many `.dna` files do you have?

Comment: There are 100 folders, Each folder has anywhere between 1- 10 `.dna` files. I am trying this on only 1 folder now which has 2 files

Comment: Each file has multiple lines, or just one very long line?

Comment: Now it has just 1 very long line.

Answer (score 3):

So the school server finally completed the task. What I realized was that for each alignment there were 1000 matrices constructed and calculated. The `align.globalxx` method has a variable  `MAX_ALIGNMENT` which is by default set to `1000`. Changing it via `monkey patching`  dint really change anything . The documentation says that, the method tries all possible alignments (yes 1000) but in my case all the matrices have the same alignment score (as well as few test sequences I tried). Finally a small piece of comment in the documentation states that if you need only 1 score, use the optional parameter `one_alignment_only` which accepts a `boolean` value only. All i did was this:

```
for a in pairwise2.align.globalmx(seq_list[0],seq_list[1],one_alignment_only=True):
    align_file.write(format_alignment(*a))
```

This reduced the time considerably. However my PC still crashed so I assume this is a very memory intensive task and requires much more `RAM` (`16gb` on a small server). So probably a more efficient way of reading the sequences in the matrix should be thought of.